# Some of my jsp pages not working in Firefox but these pages works perfectly in IE?

Tags: java, css, jsp

I have made web based applications in java these applications does not work in Firefox but these application run perfectly in IE.

I dont know whats the problem i have tried everything but still not working in the firefox.

If anybody have any idea plz let me know i will be thankful.

Comment: Can you provide more details? What behavior are you seeing in Firefox?

Comment: Actually when i entered the data into the backhnad database through my web based application which is all written in java and jsp it does not work in firefox but work in IE.Its simple web based application which just entered and update the data into the backhand database.

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and then update your question.

Comment: You need to describe the problem in developer's perspective, not in enduser's perspective. What exaclty happens? What exactly happens *not*? And that all from the moment on that the enduser presses the submit button. Check the HTTP headers, query string, the executed code in server side, etc..etc.. The question in its current form is too generic and can't be reasonably answered. Do you for instance have any webdevelopment knowledge? You can also try eliminating as much as possible code until you ends up with the smallest possible code snippet which reproduces the problem and then post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problems is between Firefox and JSP, but between Firefox and the HTML generated by your JSP.
If you have Javascript, Style Sheets, etc., the appeareance and operability can change, even to drive it not working. If you are using old versions of IE (such as IE6) these problems are even more.
You can write a very small JSP (just a hello world, without JSP scriptlets, only HTML), and try what happens in IE and firefox. If this doesnt work, maybe you have a problem with your proxy internet connection, or something similar.

Hope it helps.